# Flutter - I get error when i add import 'package:path/path.dart'

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I tried to use the image path to upload images, before my application was fine. when I try to add import 'package: path / path.dart'; and basename (image.path) for the purpose of uploading my image, I get a new error in my dialog alert. more details in context: context. This is my code:

```
import 'package:path/path.dart';

    Future uploadFile() async {
        final FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
        final userId = user.uid;
        _imageList.forEach((_image) {
          final StorageReference firebaseStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance
              .ref()
              .child('category')
              .child('food')
              .child('images')
              .child(username)
              .child(basename(_image.path));
          final StorageUploadTask task = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(_image);
          return task;
        });
      }
```

and following code where I get an error:

```
Future<void> alertSuccess() async {
    return showDialog<void>(

    /*this error*/
    context: context,
    /*------------*/

      barrierDismissible: false, // user must tap button!
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Success'),
          content: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ListBody(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                    'You success save data.'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('OK'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
                Navigator.pushReplacement(
                    context,
                    new MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => PublicService()));
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: What would be the error you get? That's by far the most essential part of your question.

Comment: Please give more details about the error. Are you looking for the code to upload an image file to the firebase storage ?

Comment: change - `alertSuccess()` to `alertSuccess(BuildContext context)`

Comment: Günter Zöchbauer and Shyju M error that appears : The argument type 'Context' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext'. [argument_type_not_assignable]

Comment: anmol.majhail I have tried the solution that you provided and managed to eliminate the error in the context section, but when I tried calling alertSuccess (); then an error appears: 1 required argument (s) expected, but 0 found. [not_enough_required_arguments] . do you have a solution for that? thanks

Comment: I know this question was asked a long time ago, but to solve your problem, when you call ` alertSuccess ();` pass it the context that you are asking for as the function parameter like so: ` alertSuccess (context);`, this context isn't coming from nowhere` when the `build` function is called it is given the `context` as a parameter.

Comment: The interesting thing is that it also happened to me, if someone can please explain why when I import the path package the whole class loses it's context and it needs to be passed to each function in the class manually. If I am supposed to pass the context as a parameter to every function that uses the context - what does the path package have to do with it? @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: Try import `import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;` and then use `path.xxx` as prefix for all function calls from that package like `path.combine(p1, p2);`. Perhaps there is a naming conflict.

Answer (score 8):

path.dart overwrites the global Context variable of the framework.
:-(
So until the path-package developers fix this, the solution from  Günter Zöchbauer in the comments is valid.
Use an alias for the package and access it through the alias.
If you have, like me, other variables called "path", you need to rename them, so e.g.:

import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;

then e.g. use

```
final imgPath = path.join(
  (await _localPath),
  '${DateTime.now()}.png',
);
```

instead of

```
final path = join(
  (await _localPath),
  '${DateTime.now()}.png',
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Every answer on above is right .I also want to answer for details on this question.I faced same issue and all you guys help me .thanks for that.

```
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;

    Future uploadFile() async {
        final FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
        final userId = user.uid;
        _imageList.forEach((_image) {
          final StorageReference firebaseStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance
              .ref()
              .child('category')
              .child('food')
              .child('images')
              .child(username)
              .child(path.basename(_image.path));
          final StorageUploadTask task = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(_image);
          return task;
        });
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use following**
`Future<void> alertSuccess() async { // your code }`